# Monte Carlo function error message

Tags: r, montecarlo

basically I have five vectors of type "double". Namely  wk_hoil, wk_gas, kwh_final17, p_hoil17 and p_gas17. All have the length 10000. I created the following function to calculate savings:

```
 fun<-function(wk1, wk2, kwh1, kwh2, p1, p2){savings<-((wk1+kwh1*p1)-(wk2+kwh2*0.7*p2))/1.05^0.5315}
```

I set up a list for the parameters:

```
param_list17<-list("wk1"=wk_hoil, "wk2"=wk_gas, "kwh1"=kwh_final17, "kwh2"=kwh_final17, "p1"=p_hoil17, "p2"=p_gas17)
```

Eventually I wanted to run a Monte Carl Simulation with the MonteCarlo function from the package MonteCarlo in R:

```
MonteCarlo(func=fun, nrep=10000, param_list = param_list17)
```

And I get the error message:

```
Error in MonteCarlo(func = fun, nrep = 10000, param_list = param_list17) : 
func has to return a list with named components. each component has to be scalar.
```

Any idea what the problem is? I'd like to save the results from the MC simulation in an vector or matrix.

Thank you!

Comment: Try with `fun <- function(wk1, wk2, kwh1, kwh2, p1, p2) { list(savings=((wk1+kwh1*p1)-(wk2+kwh2*0.7*p2))/1.05^0.5315) }`